# Как сделать так, чтобы при повороте объект не залезал за текстуру?

Tags: unity3d

скрипт, поворачивающий объект:

```
float AngleRotate = RotateSpeed * Input.GetAxis("MoveTower");
rot.z = Mathf.Clamp( rot.z + AngleRotate, -yLimit, yLimit);
Tower.transform.eulerAngles = rot;
```

Сделал вот такой код. Пушка ставится вертикально не могу понять почему и как можно это исправить?

Comment: Может: `var rot = transform.rotation` `...` `Tower.transform. = rot`, либо у вас yLimit слишком большой, поэтому пушка проворачивается слишком сильно

Answer (score 0):

использовать поворот на основе физики: Rigidbody.MoveRotation

вместо поворота который по-факту является телепортированием обьекта в другое положение. (вот в текстуры и залазит, ты же телепортируешь его)